# how to pip uninstall with virtualenv on heroku cedar stack?

Tags: python, heroku, virtualenv, pip

I tried to uninstall a module on heroku with:

heroku run  bin/python bin/pip uninstall whatever

Pip shows the module in the /app tree then claims to have uinstalled the module, but running the same command again shows it installed in the same location in the /app tree.

Is there a way to get pip uinstall to succeed?

---

Heroku run instantiates a new dyno and runs the command specified in that dyno only. Dynos are ephemeral which is why the results of the pip uninstall don't stick.

Comment: Have you confirmed in advance to source the **activate**?

Answer (score 32):

**Updated 2013-09-30:** the current way to clear the virtualenv seems to specify a different python runtime version in `runtime.txt` [as stated on Github](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/72) and in the [Heroku's devcenter reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#changing-runtimes).

Be aware that Heroku currently "only endorses and supports the use of Python 2.7.4 and 3.3.2" so unless your application supports both Python 2.7.4 and 3.3.2, you may want to test it with the runtime you'll want to switch to (currently available at `http://envy-versions.s3.amazonaws.com/$PYTHON_VERSION.tar.bz2`, though it shouldn't be an issue to switch e.g. between 2.7.4 and 2.7.3 in most cases).

Thanks @Jesse for your up-to-date [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15087542/343834) and to the commenters who made me aware of the issue.

---

**Was up-to-date in ~november 2012** (I haven't since updated the linked buildpack, my pull request was closed and the CLEAN_VIRTUALENV feature was dropped at some point by the official buildpack):

As David explained, you cannot pip uninstall one package but you can purge and reinstall the whole virtualenv. Use the [user-env-compile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) lab feature with the [CLEAN_VIRTUALENV option](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/pull/47) to purge the virtualenv:

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
heroku config:add CLEAN_VIRTUALENV=true
```

Currently this won't work because there is a bug. You'll need to use [my fork](https://github.com/blaze33/heroku-buildpack-python) of the buildpack until this [get fixed upstream](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/pull/51) (pull request was closed) :

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/blaze33/heroku-buildpack-python.git
```

Now push your new code and you'll notice that the whole virtualenv gets reinstalled.

Andrey's answer no longer works since March 23 2012. The [new style virtualenv](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/commit/6aadf1683a2e2a3f9cca1ea90cf74bf809214328) commit moved the virtual env from /app to /app/.heroku/venv but the purge branch wasn't updated to catch up so that you end up with a virtualenv not being in PYTHONHOME.

To avoid reinstalling everything after each push, disable the option:

```
heroku labs:disable user-env-compile
heroku config:remove CLEAN_VIRTUALENV BUILDPACK_URL
```

Comment: Hi @maximeR. , Impressive your solution. Works really well. I don't know why it has only my vote.

Comment: when I add the buildpack_url and I push to Heroku, I get "! Heroku push rejected, error fetching custom buildpack". Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Trying using the HTTPS version of the buildpack URL: `https://github.com/blaze33/heroku-buildpack-python.git`

Comment: The git url he had was wrong: git://github.com/blaze33/heroku-buildpack-python.git works.

Comment: mm, does heroku use *my* ssh key to fetch the buildpack ? In that case it would only work if you have the same key registered both at heroku and github, that's interesting.. Anyway, I'll edit the answer for those not having github configured (cf. [which url should i use](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use))

Comment: ok, that was a stupid idea, don't know what went wrong on the heroku side with the ssh url, anyway as everybody else said, try https or git urls until something works.

Comment: As of Aug 25th the solution works, and Heroku still haven't dealt with the pull request.

Comment: For now, its working! Looks like this buildpack got merged by Heroku. You need only to set `heroku config:add CLEAN_VIRTUALENV=true`

Comment: This worked for me however we found that the app is re complied using python 2.7.2 but we where using python 2.7.3. Setting runtime as in 'Jesse's answer worked for me....

Comment: The old buildpack led to error for me. The only (for now) supported solution is the one from Jesse a bit lower. But [soon](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/76) we should have pip-tools supporting a pip sync to handle this nicely

Answer (score 22):

There is now a simpler way to clear the pip cache. Just change the runtime environment, for example from 'python-2.7.3' to 'python-2.7.2', or vice versa.

To do this add a file called runtime.txt to the root of your repository that contains just the runtime string (as show above) in it.

For this to work you need to have turned on the Heroku labs user-env-compile feature. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

Comment: I have verified that this definitely works for the time being -- THANK YOU!

Comment: Changing the runtime works. The buildpack method no longer works for me.

Answer (score 10):

By default **virtualenv** is cached between deploys.

To avoid caching of packages you can run:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git@github.com:heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git#purge
```

That way everything will be built from scratch after you push some changes. To enable the caching just remove the BUILDPACK_URL config variable.

Now to uninstall specific package(s):

1. Remove the corresponding record(s) from the `requirements.txt`;
2. Commit and push the changes.

Thanks to Lincoln from Heroku Support Team for the clarifications.

Comment: This method doesn't seem to be working for me. Is it still working for others?

Comment: This url doesn't work for me. The url in 'Maxime R' answer has wokred

Answer (score 0):

I've created some fabfile recipes for Maxime and Jesse answers that allow re-installing the requirements with one fab command: https://gist.github.com/littlepea/5096814 (look at the docstrings for explanation and examples).

For Maxime's answer I've created a task 'heroku_clean' (or 'hc'), it'll look something like that:

```
fab heroku_clean
```

Or using an alias and specifying a heroku app:

```
fab hc:app=myapp
```

For Jesse's answer I've created a task 'heroku_runtime' (or 'hr'), it sets heroku python runtime and commits runtime.txt (also creates it if it didn't exist):

```
fab heroku_runtime:2.7.2
```

If runtime version is not passed it will just toggle it between 2.7.2 and 2.7.3, so the easiest way to change and commit the runtime is:

```
fab hr
```

Then you can just deploy (push to heroku origin) you app and the virtualenv will be rebuilt. I've also added a 'heroku_deploy' task ('hr') that I use for heroku push and scale that  also can be user together with 'heroku_runtime' task. This is  my preferred method of  deploying and rebuilding virtualenv - everything happens in one command and I can choose when to rebuild it, I don't like to do  it every time like Maxime's answer suggest because it can take a long time:

```
fab hd:runtime=yes
```

This is an equivalent of:

```
fab heroku_runtime
fab heroku_deploy
```