# Force Heroku to Recompile All Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I updated two images and now Heroku is serving one correctly but the other is still the old image.  The output of the deploy logs show both images being precompiled with new hashes but the hash used to retrieve one of them (from the `application.css` file) is still the old hash and it's grabbing the old image somehow.

I'd like to force Heroku to recompile every asset and restart the server (essentially a fresh deploy).  Currently it seems to "intelligently" only precompile the assets that it judges as being new.  I tried doing `rake assets:clobber` and `rake assets:precompile` but it changed nothing -- still using the old hash to grab the old image version for one, but successfully getting the other.  Any other options to try?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Expiring the assets manually worked -- changed  `config.assets.version = 1.0` to `1.1` in `config/production.rb`.  Still not sure what happened, though.

Comment: This has also fixed my problem with Capistrano, that was not recompiling assets even if some JS had changed

Answer (score 8):

You can now recompile assets without commiting anything.

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
```

and then

```
$ heroku repo:reset --app=appname
$ git push heroku
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736959/3034747

This command used to accomplish the same thing, but it has been removed and no longer works:

```
$ heroku repo:rebuild -a appname
```

Comment: The removed this command https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo/commit/fb1306de5813dffadc046e82cd327175ca58c44b

Comment: I also had to use `heroku repo:purge-cache --app=appname` before pushing to heroku for assets to recompile.

Comment: @ybart that's `heroku repo:purge_cache --app=appname`

Comment: Also, you can install the repo plugin like this: `heroku plugins:install heroku-repo`

Answer (score 0):

Gross, but make a small change and redeploy.

You have to actually redeploy because that's when asset compilation happens and your slug is compiled. Just restarting the server with `heroku restart`, changing config variables, or pretty much anything else won't build a new slug for you.

I just ran into this problem, and this was at least what solved it for me; YMMV.

Comment: The question states that he can see the precompile happen on the assets as he deploys. He wants to force heroku to start from scratch, which a simply change and deploy will not do.

Comment: Actually, the question says 'it seems to "intelligently" only precompile the assets that it judges as being new.' A deploy does start from scratch, but does not recompile assets if they appear unchanged(doesn't check env variables in this step). Still, @bekicot's answer looks cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

Stuff like that can happen - why don't you try using `heroku run rake assets:clean` and `heroku run rake assets:precompile` to get the assets cleaned on the server

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to change anything.  I'm having the same problem now with another app...

Comment: This will not work because all you will achieve is recompiling the assets in a fresh worker dyno. Every time a dyno is launched it uses the state from the last compilation, so any changes you make will just be thrown away when it exits.