# Heroku recognizes Django app as Node app

Tags: python, django, node.js, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Django app to Heroku. That worked fine until I installed Node.js to set up automatic LESS compilation through Grunt. Now this happens:

[image: Deployment failure]

I'm assuming that this happens because I have a `package.json` file in my root folder. How do I prevent Heroku from recognizing it as a Node.js app instead of a Django app? Currently my Node.js apps don't include anything that needs to run in production, but that could change in the future.

(PS: I apologize for not posting this as text. Long story short: I'm working in a terminal on a virtual machine.)

Comment: Do you also have a requirements.txt? That's how Heroku recognises Python projects.

Comment: I have both a `package.json` and a `requirements.txt` in my root folder. I'm assuming that Heroku finds the former first and disregards the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the default and specify your own "buildpack" by specifying a custom buildpack in the `BUILDPACK_URL` config variable:

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
```

See more in [the Heroku Buildpack Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack)

Comment: That worked, thanks! I have one more addition for people who visit this thread in the future: you'll need to rebuild your repository for the changes to take effect. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736959/217649) is how you do it without having to push a new commit.