# How to make heroku automatically run compilemessages just as it runs collectstatic

Tags: django, heroku

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

Creates compiled translation files named like `locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo` from translation source files names like `locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`.

I would like to have the `*.mo` files ignored by git and not committed to the repository, as these are not source files.

Heroku already knows to perform

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

for django projects.

How do I make it also perform `compile messages`?

Currently I work around the problem by adding the compilation result files (`*.mo`) to my repository but I'd like to know if there's a better way.

(If relevant - the repo for my site: https://github.com/yairchu/vote_tool)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a file in your project root: `bin/post_compile`
2. Add the line `./manage.py compilemessages`
3. `git push origin`
4. `git push heroku`

As you push your branch to Heroku, it should now run that command. I'm not certain whether having a custom `bin/post_compile` file will override the autodetection that Heroku does, so if you find that it's no longer running `collectstatic`, just pop that line in under your `compilemessages` line, but add `--noinput` to the line so that the management command doesn't prompt you to type "Yes" to confirm you want to overwrite existing files.

Comment: This fails for me because gettext is not installed on Heroku instances. `Can't find msgfmt. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.`

Comment: I managed to install gettext by using a gettext buildpack: https://elements.heroku.com/search/buildpacks?q=gettext