# Can't find a particular version of a dependent lib (Django/Pinax)

Tags: python, django, heroku, pinax

Based on my app I need the `django-microblogging==0.2.dev1` package, but when I put that in requirements.txt, it can't find this particular version.

And when I use the version it can find (an older version), I get errors with my application and I believe it's due to this older version.

I was able to google the 0.2.dev1 version and downloaded the source which I found here: http://dist.pinaxproject.com/dev/django-microblogging/

I untarred it and put the following in my requirements.txt file: `-I ./django-microblogging-0.2.dev1`

But now I'm getting the following error message:

`ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', '-I ./django-microblogging-0.2.dev1', 'at', ' ./django-microblogging-0.2.dev1')`

I have also tried `-I ./django-microblogging-0.2.dev1 == 0.2.dev1`

Does anyone have any idea how I can correct this error? It's totally stumping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

The issue seems to be the failure to uninstall old `django-microblogging-0.1.2` from virtualenv in heroku. Tried the method in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9463068/165603 to uninstall the previous version and it seems to work.

In particular the command used was:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git@github.com:heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git#purge
```

---

Try to put

```
django-microblogging-0.2.dev1.tar.gz
# or
path_to/django-microblogging-0.2.dev1.tar.gz
```

in `requirements.txt` directly. When you use relative path, it should be relative to the directory inside which you're running the pip.

Also, you could use

```
django-microblogging==0.2.dev1
```

Comment: Well now it can't find the dir ... I get: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_349bgfbfucapl/-I path_to/django-microblogging-0.2.dev1.tar.gz'` .... I tried both methods -- using the -I flag as above

Comment: Also if I just use the untarred folder I get the Value error still... even with path_to or not using the ./ as you suggested above -->    `ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', '-I path_to/django-microblogging-0.2.dev1', 'at', ' path_to/django-microblogging-0.2.dev1')`

Comment: @user1328021 Just use the line I wrote, don't include `-I`. If you want to use `-I`, use `pip install -I -r requirements.txt`

Comment: So when I use the tarred file (versus untarred) I get the error of the file/directory not being found. So I'm using the untarred... But the only reason I'm using -I is because when I don't use it, it says there's already an older version. Exact error without the -I: `Found existing installation: django-microblogging 0.1.2` and `Exception:
       AssertionError: Egg-link ../../../../src/microblogging does not match installed location of django-microblogging (at /tmp/build_3sy86vjvo8mvt/.heroku/src/microblogging)`

Comment: Should I close this question and make that a separate question?

Comment: @user1328021 I've tried pip w/ distribute, both `pip install -r requirements.txt`, `pip install -U -r requirements.txt` and `pip install-U -r requirements.txt` work well. Probably the error is caused by setuptools, you could try to `pip uninstall django-microblogging` at first then.

Comment: @user1328021 no need IMO, its relative and your problem still has not been solved. You could update the question for any progression.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11482/discussion-between-okm-and-user1328021)