# pip issue while deploying Django app to Heroku

Tags: django, deployment, heroku

I have an issue while trying to deploy my Django app to Heroku.

It complains about issues with installing facebook-sdk library, but actually there is
no such thing in the `requirements.txt` file.

I already tried pushing with `-f` flag, I commented out lines from requirements.txt. I've even pushed an empty requirements file and the issues still persist.

I have no idea if there is any way to reset the app or heroku's repo beside creating a new one? Any ideas what I could try?

**Console log:**

```
$ git push prod master
Counting objects: 52282, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (17957/17957), done.
Writing objects: 100% (52282/52282), 138.01 MiB | 137 KiB/s, done.
Total 52282 (delta 33410), reused 48501 (delta 30768)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Python/Django app detected
-----> Preparing Python interpreter (2.7.2)
-----> Creating Virtualenv version 1.7
       New python executable in .heroku/venv/bin/python2.7
       Also creating executable in .heroku/venv/bin/python
       Installing distribute.............................................................................................................................................................................................done.
       Installing pip...............done.
       Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-----> Activating virtualenv
-----> Installing dependencies using pip version 1.0.2
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
       Downloading/unpacking paramiko (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
       Creating supposed download cache at /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/pip_downloads
         Storing download in cache at /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/pip_downloads/http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2Fp%2Fparamiko%2Fparamiko-1.7.7.2.zip
         Running setup.py egg_info for package paramiko

       Obtaining facebook-sdk from git+http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk.git#egg=facebook-sdk (from -r requirements.txt (line 23))
         Cloning http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk.git to ./.heroku/src/facebook-sdk
         Complete output from command /usr/bin/git clone -q http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk.git /tmp/build_1bn5oykhrmms7/.heroku/src/facebook-sdk:

       ----------------------------------------
       Command /usr/bin/git clone -q http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk.git /tmp/build_1bn5oykhrmms7/.heroku/src/facebook-sdk failed with error code 128
       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python/django app
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right solution is "Maxime R."'s solution on [how to pip uninstall with virtualenv on heroku cedar stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937905/how-to-pip-uninstall-with-virtualenv-on-heroku-cedar-stack/11055852#comment14662980_11055852)

> heroku labs:enable user_env_compile heroku config:add
>   CLEAN_VIRTUALENV=true
>
> Currently this won't work because there is a bug. You'll need to use
>   my fork of the buildpack until this get fixed upstream :
>
> heroku config:add
>   BUILDPACK_URL=git@github.com:blaze33/heroku-buildpack-python.git
>
> Now push your new code and you'll notice that the whole virtualenv
>   gets reinstalled.
>
> Andrey's answer no longer works since March 23 2012. The new style
>   virtualenv commit moved the virtual env from /app to /app/.heroku/venv
>   but the purge branch wasn't updated to catch up so that you end up
>   with a virtualenv not being in PYTHONHOME.

After several attempts with heroku run command finally I applied Maxime R. solution successfully. Also I have been opened a Heroku ticket and Heroku support has been confirmed to me that this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's happen because you're using an empty repository for python-SDK's library (http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk.git), try using another repo: https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I had removed two packages from the virtual env and requirements.txt, and temporarily changing the Python runtime (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937905/how-to-pip-uninstall-with-virtualenv-on-heroku-cedar-stack/15087542#15087542)) is the only approach I found that allowed me to uninstall those packages from heroku.