# Heroku/Django Error when installing pylibmc

Tags: python, heroku, memcached

I'm getting a mile long list of errors when trying to deploy to Heroku. I followed their guid to getting started, but evidently it's lacking and inaccurate.

My settings is a module, and my requirements is a folder consisting of different .txt files for each environment:

```
settings/
  base.py
  dev.py
  heroku.py

requirements/
  base.txt
  dev.txt
  heroku.txt
```

I tried to deploy to Heroku with `pylibmc==1.2.2 django-pylibmc-sasl==0.2.4` in base.txt and in heroku.txt (which extends base.txt), and still the same.

Bug trace (small sample) :

```
_pylibmcmodule.c:2097: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyInt_FromLong’ makes integer from pointer without a cast

       /app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7/intobject.h:38: note: expected ‘long int’ but argument is of type ‘struct PylibMC_Behavior *’

       _pylibmcmodule.c:2097: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyObject_SetAttrString’ from incompatible pointer type

       /app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7/object.h:472: note: expected ‘struct PyObject *’ but argument is of type ‘struct PylibMC_Behavior *’

       _pylibmcmodule.c:2098: error: ‘PylibMC_McErr’ has no member named ‘name’

       _pylibmcmodule.c:2098: error: ‘PylibMC_McErr’ has no member named ‘exc’

       _pylibmcmodule.c:2098: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyModule_AddObject’ from incompatible pointer type

       /app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7/modsupport.h:40: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct PylibMC_Behavior *’

       _pylibmcmodule.c:2100: error: ‘PylibMC_McErr’ has no member named ‘name’

       _pylibmcmodule.c:2100: error: ‘PylibMC_McErr’ has no member named ‘exc’

       _pylibmcmodule.c: In function ‘init_pylibmc’:

       _pylibmcmodule.c:2176: error: ‘LIBMEMCACHED_VERSION_STRING’ undeclared (first use in this function)

       _pylibmcmodule.c:2176: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘PyModule_AddStringConstant’ from incompatible pointer type

       /app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7/modsupport.h:42: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct PylibMC_Behavior *’

       error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

       ----------------------------------------
       Command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/app/build/pylibmc/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-i0GDaz-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in /app/build/pylibmc
       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507639/memcached-on-heroku-w-django-cant-install-pylibmc-memcacheify) related post, that's what gave an idea of trying to add the libs to base.txt, but still no help.

Answer (score 2):

Pylibmc is automatically supported if you have it present in requirements.txt.

Having all of those requirements files is just extra overhead. Check out [Twelve-Factor's Dev/Prod Parity](http://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity) article.