# Dokku install libmemcached

Tags: django, deployment, libmemcached, dokku

I am trying to deploy Django application with Dokku.

My `requirements.txt` contains `django-pylibmc` that requires pre-installed `libmemcached`.
So when I push my repo it fails with this message:

```
remote:        In file included from _pylibmcmodule.c:34:0:
remote:
remote:        _pylibmcmodule.h:42:36: fatal error: libmemcached/memcached.h: No such file or directory
remote:
remote:        compilation terminated.
remote:
remote:        error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
remote:
```

I thought to solve it using [memcached plugin](https://github.com/jezdez/dokku-memcached-plugin) but as I understand that just creates separate container where memcached is installed.

So the question is: What do I need to do to make that pip installation work?
Can I somehow also include `apt-get install libmemcached` step in dokku push?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11587142/445267). It seems to be the case also for Heroku.
As the answer states, the problem is that heroku(dokku) python buildpacks requires explicit `pylibmc` specification in `requirements.txt`.