# Does heroku use my ssh key to fetch builpacks?

Tags: heroku, ssh, github

Heroku gives you the possibility to use a custom buildpack using the `BUILDPACK_URL` env variable.

That worked fine with `git@github.com:user/repo.git` urls until someone had [trouble fetching the buildpack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11055852/343834).

Until now I assumed heroku managed to fetch buildpacks on its own but it seems it uses my heroku ssh key to do this.

And it just appears to work because I registered the same ssh key at github. Is it the case ?

Comment: Why not using an https address for the BUILPACK (like https://github.com/blaze33/heroku-buildpack-python.git)? That way, no need to mess with ssh keys (not needed for read access only)

Comment: Yes, that's how I edited my linked  answer. Still, I was curious to understand how heroku manage ssh urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not use your SSH key. You only upload the public part of the key, so using your key would be impossible.

Comment: Good point, they just work in pair, just feels stupid now ^^ My initial assumption was that heroku uses its own key pair when told to fetch something with an ssh url but started to make weird explanations as why it would not work...