# Heroku is running the wrong app

Tags: django, heroku

I accidentally uploaded another app to my Heroku folder called social... so I have two apps -- `spicestore` and `social` now. Rather than running `python spicestore/manage.py runserver` Heroku is running `python social/manage.py runserver`. I deleted the folder `social` off of Heroku by running a bash terminal and out of my git folder, but that didn't set it back.

How can I explicitly tell it where to point, and also delete `social` from my Heroku directory for good?

Comment: heroku clone your environment for each request, that means, you can delete all files from your execution instance, the next instance will be cloned again with all files. Should be enough to push old app again. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937905/how-to-pip-uninstall-with-virtualenv-on-heroku-cedar-stack

Answer (score 0):

If `spicestore` is the app in your git repository, and `social` is not in your git repository, then when you push your application to heroku via `git push -f`, `social` will be overwritten.  You should not need to use a bash shell or any system other than git to switch apps.