# Heroku installing outdated requirements file

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Im attempting to deploy a Django app using Heroku.

When I first ran

```
$ git push heroku master
```

My original requirements.txt had outdated dependencies and Django failed to deploy. After I edited my dependencies and attempted to deploy I noticed that Heroku is still attempting to install dependencies that I erased. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: See this post, perhaps can helps to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937905/how-to-pip-uninstall-with-virtualenv-on-heroku-cedar-stack

Comment: Danihp is most likely correct assuming the outdated dependencies did not fail and were actually installed. And on a more basic level, make sure you have done `git add` and `git commit` for the new requirements file and not gone straight to `git push`.

Comment: thanks. moving a little too fast here.