# Getting the right dependency in Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

I am trying to have Heroku take an [editable dependency](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip) (i.e. `-e git://github.com/merlinares/django-registration.git#egg=django-registration`) with pip requirements.

However, even though it appears to be taking that fork on deploy, it is not actually using it. I have checked the code in site-packages with `heroku run cat .heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/forms.py` and it doesn't include the new code, but just uses the default django-registration package which was previously installed.

However, the forked version seems to exist in the directory specified by `django-registration.egg-link`, a directory named:

/app/.heroku/src/django-registration

On deploy (i.e. `git push heroku master`) I see:

```
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.3.1)

   Obtaining django-registration from git+git://github.com/mattlinares/django-registration.git#egg=django-registration (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
     Updating ./.heroku/src/django-registration clone
     Running setup.py egg_info for package django-registration

   Installing collected packages: django-registration

     Running setup.py develop for django-registration

       Creating /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django-registration.egg-link (link to .)
       django-registration 0.8-alpha-1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

       Installed /app/.heroku/src/django-registration
   Successfully installed django-insensitive django-registration
   Cleaning up...
```

I've also manually tried to uninstall and install that particular fork, with this effect:

```
(ssc)~/code/django/ssc: heroku run pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/mattlinares/django-registration.git
Running `pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/mattlinares/django-registration.git` attached to terminal... up, run.5704
Downloading/unpacking git+git://github.com/mattlinares/django-registration.git
  Cloning git://github.com/mattlinares/django-registration.git to /tmp/pip-qpTF2t-build
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from git+git://github.com/mattlinares/django-registration.git

Installing collected packages: django-registration
  Found existing installation: django-registration 0.8-alpha-1
    Uninstalling django-registration:
      Successfully uninstalled django-registration
  Running setup.py install for django-registration

Successfully installed django-registration
Cleaning up...
```

Yet my app is not using the version of `registration` I am trying to feed it. I'm suspecting the eggs which are listed with `heroku run ls .heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages`:

```
django_registration-0.8-py2.7.egg-info        registration
```

django-registration.egg-link

I've also tried to purge the whole virtualenv as per [how to pip uninstall with virtualenv on heroku cedar stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937905/how-to-pip-uninstall-with-virtualenv-on-heroku-cedar-stack) with no luck

What can I do?

Comment: any luck with this?  i have the same issue with another dependency.

Comment: No luck. I think I scrapped the plan and overrode the form I was trying to edit from within my app, which is preferable. But there is, of course, still a Heroku problem here. One should be able to use a different fork. Have you tried renaming your fork e.g. in this case that would be django-registration-myfork?

Comment: actually my issue is with a dependency that I control.  Heroku app A depends on django app B, both of which are my code.  But django app B is on bitbucket so that I can build it *easily* with heroku.  i have been creating tags for app B versions (v0.1.x) and bumping those with each new commit that i want to include in Heroku app A.  I update Heroku app A's requirements.txt to include the new tag reference.  It's kind of a pain.

Comment: Can you post your pip freeze output for the venv deploying to heroku?

Answer (score 0):

When using editable dependencies you have to define a tag or commit-hash.

Following your example:

```
-e git+https://github.com/merlinares/django-registration.git@3.1#egg=django-registration
```

or

```
-e git+https://github.com/merlinares/django-registration.git@40fee813ca444236da6d66f516b869fd8ebbe9cd#egg=django-registration
```