# Cannot get custom form validations working

Tags: python, django, registration

I am subclassing django-registration's basic `RegistrationForm` in my own app so have:

forms.py

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
"""
Form for registering a new user account.

Validates that the requested username is not already in use, and
requires the password to be entered twice to catch typos.

Subclasses should feel free to add any additional validation they
need, but should avoid defining a ``save()`` method -- the actual
saving of collected user data is delegated to the active
registration backend.

"""

print 'Custom Form'

def clean_password1(self):
    """
    Verify that password is longer than 5 characters.

    """

    password = self.cleaned_data['password1']
    print 'Custom Validator'
    if len(password) < 6:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Password needs to be at least 6 characters long"))
    return self.cleaned_data

def clean_email(self):
    """
    Validate that the supplied email address is unique for the site.

    """
    if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data['email']):
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("This email address is already in use. \
            Please supply a different email address."))
    return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^register/$', 'registration.views.register',
{'form_class':CustomRegistrationForm,
    'backend':'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend' }, name='registration_register'),
```

...which should work to add my validations. When I load the form, `Custom form` prints to the console but `Custom validator` does not'. If I put `print 'Custom validator'` in the same place in a custom validator in `RegistrationForm` in the django-registration package in the virtualenv site-packages, it does print to the console when the form is called.

Of course, the problem is that custom validation doesn't work when it is subclassed inside my own app. For some reason, my custom form is running but the validators aren't, even though they are identical.

I have tried different def names like `clean(self)` and `clean_password(self)`. I have tried many, many other fixes which have taken me far down the rabbit hole (e.g. forking my own version of registration to be installed by pip on heroku, with [its own batch of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255953/getting-the-right-dependency-in-heroku)). This subclassing is the cleanest way though and I feel it should be working.

Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Your `clean_password1` looks ok, except you should return `password` at the end, and not the custom validator.

Note that django registration 1.0 has now been released. It has been rewritten to use class based views. Try upgrading, you might fix your problem in the process.

Comment: I took your advice and installed django-registration 1.0 which made no difference. I also tried replacing the last line as `return self.cleaned_data['password1']` with no luck. Bear in mind that this exact code works when used in the registration site package form (also in 1.0). Also the email validation isn't working either. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you manage to get it working.